# Test if RadioButton IsChecked

Tags: silverlight

In Silverlight, how can I test in a simple if/then if a RadioButton is checked?  I searched around for how to do it, but I didn't understand how to use binding.  Is there a way to do it with a if/then?

Comment: You should learn how to use bindings.  You're missing out on the most powerful feature of WPF / Silverlight.

Comment: can you recommend any good tutorials for learning bindings?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (someControl.IsChecked)
```